# Can't uninstall Multitasking View and Stopwatch and Timer Apps

Tags: appcenter, multitasking-view

I just switched to Elementary OS and love it!

I've gotten rid of apps that it comes with, either through the App Center or using terminal commands, and also following various article suggestions.

I have the latest version of Elementary OS and have been using Linux for ~6 months (pic below of the Multitasking View and Stopwatch & Timer apps).  Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Multitasking view is not an app but just a button to switch to multitasking view. As far as I know, it can't be removed.

You can use the following command to find the relevant package for the stopwatch & timer app as I don't seem to have the app on my system.

```
apt list --installed
```

You can also try this:

1. Open Files with administrator privileges. (Right Click on icon.)
2. Type `/opt` in the address bar.
3. Delete the application you want.
4. Go to `/home/abrattic/.local/share/applications` or `/usr/share/applications` and delete the *.desktop file of relevant program.

Comment: I used that command, but I couldn't find the program anywhere.  I thought maybe it would be next to all the apps starting with "s", but there was nothing there that could've been it.  

I've since emailed it's developers for help on the matter, thanks for the reply still abbratic, I appreciate it.

Comment: @cytosage I added another way to fix this in my answer.